# Google is indexing different pages of the same list

Tags: seo, google-search, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, prestashop

I have a category page that is a paginated list of products of an ecommerce website and google is indexing:

- www.myshop.com/category-list
- www.myshop.com/category-list?p=2
- www.myshop.com/category-list?p=7

Of course I want google to follow all the pages to index all the products but I don't want to index the category page more than once. What should I do?

The website is based on Prestashop platform v1.6 if you find that useful/important.

Comment: "I don't want to index the category page more than once." - But `p=2` and `p=3` are presumably different "pages" with different content? So, why don't you want them indexed?

Comment: Yeah w3dk, that is why I said, he can index those webpage also without worry about SEO.

Comment: @w3dk and Goyllo thanks for your replies. They are different pages indeed but they have the same title, description... if I have 500 pages, do you think it make sense to index all of them?

Comment: Change a title based on pagination as I said in answer, for meta description I will say just don't use at all, Google will pick up automatically based on user query. If content is different than other then I will say go with 500+ pages as well and you really not need to de-index them with any technique. In recent official hangout of Google webmaster I ask one question "Do Google assign PageRank for noindex webpage as well as like normal webpages" and they simply said no. So your all indexed webpage is somehow improving your website SEO automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine to index your paginated content in Google search result, you can set different title for that, for example

```
for www.myshop.com/category-list?p=2 you can set title as "Page 2 - product category"
for www.myshop.com/category-list?p=3 you can set title as "Page 3 - product category
```

But if you really don't want to index other categories paginated webpages then simply [use the noindex meta tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noindex).

For example if you implement below meta tags in `<head>` section of any webpage.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Then that page will not going to appear in search result. But Google will still crawl that URL and pass the all the ranking benefits as like normal, it's just used for to prevent indexing.

I don't know have idea about Prestashop, so i don't know how you gonna implement it, but I just want to say, you have to add that meta tags on those pages only which you don't want to index. I mean don't implement that tags on your all webpages othewise your all webpages will be deindex by Google. I am saying that because may be your Prestashop use parent heading section on all webpages, so you have to add some if else code first.

So above Meta tags is easiest way to implement from client side, but if you're server side fan, then you can also [use x-robots-tag](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag).

Comment: As well, using the canonical tag on the pages back to the one page without the parameters will, in effect, make sure that the correct page ranks and the parameter pages virtually disappear. Cheers!!

Comment: Yeah that is another option as well.

Comment: Should I add that as an answer in Russian??

Comment: @closetnoc canonical is more like to handle duplicate contents issue, but I know it's also work for that as well.

Comment: That is one reason why I leave these little turdlings... they are just thoughts. I realize that the canonical tag is not the only answer or even a complete one, but rather, a point that should be made just in case (JIC) it is important. Cheers Mate!!

Comment: @closetnoc I kinda wonder whether a `rel="canonical"` would work here? It is certainly a valid suggestion. However, if the page that is stated as "canonical" is _very different_, which presumably the first page of the paginated series probably is, then this may not be honoured. (?) [Google acknowledges that you can use a `rel="canonical"`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en) to reference a "View All" page. In this case, the content is presumably "part of" the _view all_ page, so a canonical is reasonable here.

Comment: @w3dk Another good point! I guess it depends upon what the parameters do. You and goyllo are more expert in this area than I hope to be. I will let great minds figure it out. Cheers!! (kind souls)

Comment: @w3dk  I have never seen any option like "View All page" in search, did you see that before? I really want to know more about it. . Actually I was going to add canonical link tag as closetnoc said, but may be in future OP need to use that tag for preferred version, but "view all" concept I did not get it.

Comment: @Goyllo I have seen it implemented, however, most sites probably don't because it's impractical to list an "enormous" number of items on a single page. Instead, they give the option to view 10, 50, 100, etc. per page. If the complete-list is _within reason_, then a "View All" page is a good addition IMO. A "View All" page can be much easier to _search_. Although "500 pages" of 100 items is probably impractical!

Comment: Yeah I am also [watching](https://youtu.be/njn8uXTWiGg?t=194) about that, and displaying many webpages content in single webpage is probably not good idea for UX(If it take many seconds to load). If there are 10 webpages then it make sense, but for hundred it is not. Now I get it that View All means, all of the paginated content should be place in one simple webpage and that webpage link should be used as canonical by other webpages. So webmaster did not face duplicate content issue.